# Merge [go-echo] and [echo-framework] tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

As of this writing:

- [go-echo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go-echo) has 11 questions

  > Echo is a high performance, extensible, minimalist Go web framework. This tag should be used with general questions concerning the Echo framework or any related middleware,
- [echo-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/echo-framework) has 22 questions

  > Echo is a high-performance, minimalist Go web framework.

These should be merged. Although [echo-framework] is the more popular, I might suggest keeping [go-echo], but merging either way would be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[echo-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/echo-framework) seemed like a generic name, and I was a bit worried that there were other "Echo frameworks". Luckily for us, all the 22 questions were related to the Go's Echo framework, which is already covered by the tag, [go-echo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go-echo).

I added [echo-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/echo-framework) as a synonym for [go-echo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go-echo), that is:

- [go-echo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go-echo) × 11 ← [echo-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/echo-framework) × 22